# Difficulty grasping JavaScript closures (i.e., why isn't this for loop working?)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

I've searched the FAQ and I've seen examples but I can't seem to grasp why this isn't working. I'd really appreciate any hints at all as to what I'm doing wrong.
All I'm trying to do is take a word and on button click display images one at a time for each letter, spelling out the word (and images should fade in/out). 
It's the classic "for loop only shows last item" problem but the thing is, the console logs correctly. The variable changes, but only the last image displays. Again I truly appreciate any help understanding what I'm doing wrong as I know it's important to fully grasp this. Code below (I left out the HTML as it's just a div that gets updated and a button):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var word = 'abc';

  $('#newWordButton').click(function () {
    function animateLetters() {
      function changeLetter() {
        for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
          var currentLetter = word.charAt(i);
          console.log(currentLetter);
          $('#wordsDiv').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $('#wordsDiv').replaceWith('<img src = "images/letters/' + currentLetter + '.gif" />');
            $('#wordsDiv').fadeIn(1000);
          });
        }
      }
      setTimeout(changeLetter, 1000);
    }

    animateLetters();
  });
});
```

Comment: At least indent your code properly so people can see the function scope more easily. Thanks to @Yoshi for fixing it.

Comment: Why are you defining `animateLetters` inside of the click handler? It will be defined each time the element is clicked...

Comment: bjornd -- I realize it's a possible duplicate and in fact stated that I'm aware it's been answered but that I don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `currentLetter` a closure by passing the value as an argument to a self-executing function. This will retain the value for you when your function executes.

Untested example:

```
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    (function (currentLetter) {
        console.log(currentLetter);
        $('#wordsDiv').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $('#wordsDiv').replaceWith('<img src = "images/letters/' + currentLetter + '.gif" />');
            $('#wordsDiv').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    )(word.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: That's doesn't answer his question, it might solve the problem, but it doesn't help their understanding.

Comment: I am typing out the explanation, sorry.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still having trouble understanding a bit (please forgive me, I'm a complete noob and none too bright to boot). So does the first function return currentLetter?

Comment: What I'm not grasping is the parentheses around the first function. I've not seen that notation and don't understand why it's needed/what it means.

Comment: @theFinalPastry, the parens around the function is to allow it to be a self-executing function. `(function (arg1Closure) {...})(arg1);` makes a function and executes it immediately with the arguments saved in that scope (i.e. a closure). Your lack of understanding is because I am not explaining it well.

Comment: No, you just explained it fantastically! I finally get it! Thanks so much gpojd for your patience and kindness. I'm sorry I don't have points to give you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that closures are defined by the scope of a function, and not just any pair of angled brackets.  Since a for loop isn't a function definition, it doesn't form a closure.

@gpojd provided a workable bit of code, I think.  But there's more information on the [closure FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures), like:

- [How do Closures Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- [Javascript closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [Javascript infamous loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Comment: Thanks, yes I read those but I'm right thick so need a bit more hand-holding. I really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The closure isn't the half of your problems...

The for loop prevented anything from actually being animated... You were replacing the `#wordsDiv` with an image, so it couldn't possibly exist for the next image.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/P8Lz5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var word = 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis';
    $('#newWordButton').click(animateLetters);

    function animateLetters() {
        (function changeLetter(i) {
            if (i == word.length) return;

            var currentLetter = word.charAt(i);
            console.log(currentLetter);

            $('#wordsDiv').empty();
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/&text=' + currentLetter;

            img.onload = function() {
                $(img).appendTo('#wordsDiv').hide().fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $('#wordsDiv img').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        changeLetter(i + 1);
                    });
                });
            };
        })(0);
    }
});​
```

Or see here if you want the letters to fade in one at a time to form a word: http://jsfiddle.net/P8Lz5/1/

Comment: Thank you, I finally get it. Sorry for being so thick.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is function-scoped. Every time you create a new function, it:

1. Gets a scope object which holds its own declared variables (including argument variables)
2. Has a reference to the scope in which it was defined, which is walked at runtime when you attempt to access a variable that isn't present in the function's own scope.

So, looking at a slightly edited version of your code (added `var` to the loop so `i` isn't global, removed the `animateLetters()` wrapper layer):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var word = 'abc';

  $('#newWordButton').click(function () {
    function changeLetter() {
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var currentLetter = word.charAt(i);
        $('#wordsDiv').fadeOut(1000, function () {
          $('#wordsDiv').replaceWith('<img src = "images/letters/' + currentLetter + '.gif" />');
          $('#wordsDiv').fadeIn(1000);
        });
      }
    }
    setTimeout(changeLetter, 1000);
  });
});
```

This is what the resulting scopes which are generated look like (with a scope represented by square brackets):

```
[global] - this is the fallback scope, and how every reference to $ is resolved
| var $
+-[function()] (passed to ready call)
  | var word
  +-[function()] (passed to click call)
    | var changeLetter
    +-[function changeLetter()]
      | var i = 4
      | var currentLetter = 'c'
      +-[function()] (passed to 1st fadeOut call)
      | |
      +-[function()] (passed to 2nd fadeOut call)
      | |
      +-[function()] (passed to 3rd fadeOut call)
        |
```

When your fadeOut functions are called, they walk up the scope chain to find the `currentLetter` variable when it's accessed, as they don't have one in their own scope. Notice that they all have access to the *same* parent scope, so they're all accessing the same `currentLetter` variable which, after the `for` loop has exited, will be pointing at `'c'`.

---

This is what the bottom of the scope diagram looks like when you use @gpojd's solution (but don't forget to add `var i` to the loop expression!), after the `for` loop has exited:

```
[function changeLetter()]
| var i = 4
+-[function()] (IIFE in 1st loop iteration)
| | var currentLetter = 'a'
| +-[function()] (passed to 1st fadeOut call)
|   |
+-[function()] (IIFE in 2nd loop iteration)
| | var currentLetter = 'b'
| +-[function()] (passed to 2nd fadeOut call)
|   |
+-[function()] (IIFE in 3rd loop iteration)
  | var currentLetter = 'c'
  +-[function()] (passed to 3rd fadeOut call)
    |
```

The solution is using an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (IIFE) to create an intermediate function scope on each loop iteration, which passes the value of the character at the current value of `i` into what becomes a `currentLetter` variable in its own scope - now when your fadeOut functions are called, they find and use the `currentLetter` variable in the function scope created by the IIFE.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I will be spending a good deal of time with your thorough example. I was about to give up and thanks to you and the others I'm learning something. Truly appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome :) Recommended reading: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/